# Remove a class from all ID's that begin with username-

Tags: jquery

I have a bunch of elements that look like

```
<div id="username-2343"></div>
```

I need to loop through all of them on the page and remove a class from them using **jQuery**.

How can I do this? **I don't know all the ID's so I need to search for all matching username.**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This should do it with the [`attributeStartsWith`](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/attributeStartsWith#attributevalue) selector:

```
$('div[id^=username-]').removeClass('myclass');
```

Presumably, however, you have control of these `<div>`s as they are printed onto the page. It would be in better taste to simply give them all a class signifying they are a "user div", so then you can just do:

```
$('div.user').removeClass('myclass');
```

This would be both faster and cleaner.